# woocommerce - programmatically update cart item quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to programmatically update the quantity of a specific product in the cart if certain criteria is met.

I can easily update the price of the cart items with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wwpa_simple_add_cart_price' );
function wwpa_simple_add_cart_price( $cart_object ) {
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
                $value['data']->price = '1';
}}
```

In the function above I tried to add:

```
$value['data']->quantity= '10';
```

This doesn't work but not quite sure how or if I can edit the quantity?

I also tried a these combinations that I found while digging around WooCommerce:

```
$value['data']->quantity= '10';
$value['data']->qty= '10';
$value['quantity'] = '10';
```

Again none of these worked.

Comment: A non-programmatic way is to modify the add to cart shortcode url format as follows `href="/?add-to-cart=41&quantity=99"`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There has been some changes to the WC_Cart class since this post originally got posted, so i updated it with the new changes.

To update the quantity:

```
WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 100);
```

How to get the $cart_item_key example:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    echo $cart_item_key;
}
```

And another example with a known cart_item_key:

```
WC()->cart->set_quantity('8d317bdcf4aafcfc22149d77babee96d', 100);
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: @shish do you know how to update a cart item attribute, like 'size' or 'color'?