# Update Order Programmatically Doesn't Update Totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update the quantities of an ordered product and when doing so I would like the order to reflect the actual cost. What I find happens is that the Product Cost is reduced to match the total and the order total is never actually updated. I've supplied a simple sample below:

```
function prefix_update_woo_order() {

    $order_id       = 123; // This needs to be a real order or there will be errors
    $order_item_id  = 5; // This needs to be a real order item ID or there will be errors.

    $order       = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    $order_items[ $order_item_id ]->set_quantity( 2 );

    $order->calculate_taxes();
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'prefix_update_woo_order' );
```

For example, a "Beanie with Logo" product is on sale for $18.00 and I originally buy 1. I want to programmitically update the order item to a quantity of 2 instead of 1 after the order has been placed. I would expect the total to be $36.00 but what I'm finding is that the product cost changes to match the total price. Instead of a cost of $18.00 for a "Beanie with Logo" the quantity is updated to 2 and the cost is reduced to $9.00ea.

In short, what I want to do is update an existing order items quantity and have the totals updated to reflect the new quantity cost, discount, taxes. What methods do I need to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I think this code will change your problem

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'test_order_update_order' );
function test_order_update_order() {
    $order_id       = 80; // This needs to be a real order or there will be errors
    $order_item_id  = 11; // This needs to be a real order item ID or there will be errors.
    $quantity = 2;  //quantity which you want to set.
    $order       = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $order_items as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $order_item_id == $key ) {
           $product_value = $value->get_data();
           $product_id    = $product_value['product_id']; 
        }
    }
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $price = ( int ) $quantity * $price;
    $order_items[ $order_item_id ]->set_quantity( 2 );
    $order_items[ $order_item_id ]->set_subtotal( $price );
    $order->calculate_taxes();
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: Using something like `$total = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $line_item->get_quantity() ) );` may be a better solution as `$price` may not always end up an Integer - it could be a float.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried what you are trying to achieve before. What i see in your code is that `$order_items` is an array of Items Objects produced from `WC_Order::get_items()`, but i dont see the WC_Order Instance being notified that the order items have changed. I would expect a method like `$order->update_cart($order_items);` I believe i found some usefull links for more research
https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/WC_Order/-/php-wc_order-class-examples.html
[woocommerce - programmatically update cart item quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040446/woocommerce-programmatically-update-cart-item-quantity)

Sorry, i was not much of help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the follows code snippet to do the above task -

```
function prefix_update_woo_order() {

    $order_id       = 123; // This needs to be a real order or there will be errors
    $order_item_id  = 5; // This needs to be a real order item ID or there will be errors.

    $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if( $order && !wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_order_item_data_updated', true ) ) {
        $item_price = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_line_total', true );
        $updated_item_quantity = 2;
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_qty', $updated_item_quantity );
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_line_total', $item_price * $updated_item_quantity );

        $order->calculate_totals();
        $order->save();
        // set flag
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_order_item_data_updated', true, true );
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'prefix_update_woo_order' );
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with. I've tried to use the [`wc_format_decimal()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_format_decimal.html) where applicable. Seems like a lot of work to simply update an order items quantity but it is what it is.

The bottom comment is unnecessary but if you're using the [Cost of Goods plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-cost-of-goods/) then that will take care of that.

```
/**
 * Update the order item quantity and totals
 * @param Integer $order_id
 * @param Integer $order_item_id
 * @param Integer $quantity         - Quantity to set
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_update_woo_order( $order_id, $order_item_id, $quantity ) {

    // Get Order, Item, and Product Data
    $order          = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_items    = $order->get_items();
    $line_item      = $order_items[ $order_item_id ];
    $variation_id   = $line_item->get_variation_id();
    $product_id     = $line_item->get_product_id();
    $product        = wc_get_product( $variation_id ? $variation_id : $product_id );
    $quantity_old   = $line_item->get_quantity();

    // Calculate Old and New Discounts
    $discount = wc_format_decimal( $line_item->get_subtotal() - $line_item->get_total(), '' );
    if( ! empty( $discount ) ) {
        $discount_per_qty = wc_format_decimal( ( $discount / $quantity_old ), '' );
        $discount = wc_format_decimal( ( $discount_per_qty * $quantity ), '' );
    }

    // Set Quantity and Order Totals
    $line_item->set_quantity( $quantity );
    $total = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $line_item->get_quantity() ) );  // Also see `wc_get_price_excluding_tax()`
    $line_item->set_subtotal( $total );             // Without Discount
    $line_item->set_total( $total - $discount );    // With Discount

    // Save Everything
    $line_item->save();
    wc_save_order_items( $order_id, $order_items );

    /**
     * If using the 'Cost of Goods' Plugin
     * - - - - - -
     * $cog         = $line_item->get_meta( '_wc_cog_item_cost', true );
     * $new_cog     = wc_format_decimal( ( $quantity * $cog ), '' );
     * $line_item->update_meta_data( '_wc_cog_item_total_cost', $new_cog );
     * wc_cog()->set_order_cost_meta( $order_id, true );
     */

}
```